# Sum of SQL Function return value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Query:

```
Select Top 3 dbo.FN_GetLRExpenseAmount(VendorBillID,LRNo,PM.PickupRunsheetNo)
From PickupRunsheetMaster PM Left Outer Join
     PickupRunsheetDetail PRD
     ON PM.PickupRunsheetNo = PRD.PickupRunsheetNo
Where ISNULL(VendorBillID,0) > 0
```

Output:

```
601.90
14.56
145.62
```

When I sum the return value of function `dbo.FN_GetLRExpenseAmount(VendorBillID,LRNo,PM.PickupRunsheetNo)` throuth below query then it does not return any value

```
Select Top 3 SUM(dbo.FN_GetLRExpenseAmount(VendorBillID, LRNo, PM.PickupRunsheetNo))
From PickupRunsheetMaster PM Left Outer Join
     PickupRunsheetDetail PRD
     ON PM.PickupRunsheetNo = PRD.PickupRunsheetNo
Where ISNULL(VendorBillID,0) > 0
```

Answer (score 4):

The queries are not the same.  The `TOP 3` does nothing in the second query, because it is an aggregation query that returns only one row.

For an equivalent query, use a subquery or CTE:

```
select sum(val) as sum_3
from (Select Top 3 dbo.FN_GetLRExpenseAmount(VendorBillID, LRNo, PM.PickupRunsheetNo) as val
      From PickupRunsheetMaster PM Left Outer Join
           PickupRunsheetDetail PRD
           ON PM.PickupRunsheetNo = PRD.PickupRunsheetNo
      Where ISNULL(VendorBillID,0) > 0
     ) x
```

Comment: @AmreshKumarSingh . . . When using `TOP` you should also use `ORDER BY`.  The subquery (and your original query) return three arbitrary matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

TOP 3 SUM gives you this result. To get the sum value of the top 3 records you want, Create a subquery:

```
SELECT
     SUM(A.Expense)
FROM
(
    Select Top 3 dbo.FN_GetLRExpenseAmount(VendorBillID, LRNo, PM.PickupRunsheetNo) AS [Expense]
    From PickupRunsheetMaster PM Left Outer Join
         PickupRunsheetDetail PRD
         ON PM.PickupRunsheetNo = PRD.PickupRunsheetNo
    Where ISNULL(VendorBillID,0) > 0
) AS A
```